# LDAP PHP authentification with two OU?

Tags: php, authentication, ldap

I have a PHP script with LDAP authentication that works fine. Now, I have the problem that I want to search in two OUs. I need this because we do a windows migration and have temporary two OUs. I want that if the member is not in the first OU, search the user in the second OU.

Here is my code. I thought I could duplicate my line and rename the OU in `ldap_dn2` and `CompanyNew`:

```
$ldap_dn = "OU=Company,DC=mydomain,dc=de";
$ldap_dn2 = "OU=CompanyNew,DC=mydomain,dc=de";
```

But whats next? How can I check this in my code:

For the one OU I have:

`$result = ldap_search($ldap, $ldap_dn, $filter, $attr) or exit("LDAP-Server kann nicht durchsucht werden!");`

How can a say "okay, not found in `$result`, so search in `$ldap_dn2`"?

EDITED: a friend helped me and this is the solution:

```
function performLDAPSearch($ldap, $ldap_dn, $ldap_dn_2, $filter, array $attr)
{
    $result = ldap_search($ldap, $ldap_dn, $filter, $attr);
    $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
    if (!$entries || count($entries) == 0) {
        $result = ldap_search($ldap, $ldap_dn_2, $filter, $attr);
    }
    if (!$result) {
        exit("LDAP-Server kann nicht durchsucht werden!");
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: What does `$result` contain when the first search fails?

Comment: You can use an `or` type syntax in the ldap query so it will automatically search both ous.

Comment: my user is in the first $ldap_dn and a echoed the $result and got a "0". i thougt i can say "if result==0 search $ldap_dn2..but this doesnt work

Comment: you mean: $result = ldap_search($ldap, $ldap_dn, $filter, $attr) or ldap_search($ldap, $ldap_dn2, $filter, $attr) exit("LDAP-Server kann nicht durchsucht werden!");? this doesnt work :/

Comment: What parameter are you filtering on? The user's firstname,lastname, username, uid ??

Comment: $filter = "(sAMAccountName=".$user.")";
  $attr = array("memberof");

Comment: $result = ldap_search($ldap,"dc=mydomain,dc=de",$filter);
        ldap_sort($ldap,$result,"sn");
        $infos = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
        for ($i=0; $i<$infos["count"]; $i++)
        {
            if($infos['count'] > 1)
                break;
   $name = $infos[$i]["cn"][0];
        }

Comment: Rather than adding details in comments, please [edit] your question to add requested information. You can then comment saying that you have done so. Comments here may get hidden by "show more comments" or could be deleted without notice.  Editing updates into your question ensures that they don't get lost and that everybody who wants to answer the question sees them.